# Storing computed values in an array

Tags: c#, performance, array

In several places I need to compute the next value, given a N:

```
double size = 1.0 / Math.Pow(2, N);
```

Since I won't be computing this value for N > 15 I have thought of the following performance optimization:

```
    public static readonly double[] RegionSizes =
{
    1, 0.5, 0.25, 0.125, 0.0625, 0.03125, 0.015625, 0.0078125,
    0.00390625, 0.001953125, 0.000976563, 0.000488281, 0.000244141, 0.00012207, 0.00006103515625, 0.000030517578125
};


//Usage
    double size = RegionSizes[N];
```

Is this a good solution? Why / why not?

Comment: Why don't you test it for a trillion iterations and see?

Comment: "Is this a good solution?" It depends on how often and how you're going to use it. By the looks of it though, it looks like micro-optimization. Probably in the wrong place too.

Answer (score 5):

It isn't a good solution and there are several reasons.

1.: Your values are less precise than what the double data type allows for. For example,

```
1.0 / Math.Pow(2, 12)
```

computes to 0.000244140625, while your lookup value is just 0.000244141. Depending on the following calculations, this can make quite a big difference.

2.: Your array is public and mutable. While the array reference is readonly (so you can't assign a new array to the reference), the array itself is not. For example

```
RegionSizes[2] = 5;
```

compiles and runs without any problems. You (or every other dev) can override values in the array as he desires. Better use an immutable collection, like `ReadOnlyCollection<double>`, to prevent your cached values from manipulation during runtime. (If this is a little fun-project with you as the only dev this might not become a problem; in bigger projects with >1 dev this type of oversight can lead to hard-to-track bugs.)

3.: Experience tells that assumptions like

> I won't be computing this value for N > 15

do not always hold true. To be sure, a more flexible approach (like calculating every value once it's first needed, then store it and use it when needed again) would allow for more flexibility. Of course, without any information about what you intend to do in your program it's hard to tell if this is relevant.

4.: I strongly suspect you are doing premature optimizations (because you mention neither actual performance problems, nor any measurements indicating that floting-point operations are the cause for such problems). Donald Knuth said

> The real problem is that programmers have spent far too much time worrying about efficiency in the wrong places and at the wrong times; premature optimization is the root of all evil (or at least most of it) in programming.

and I have nothing to add. From my experience, in >95% of all software projects you don't need to worry about the performance of >95% of your code. So when making an optimization, you should follow these steps:

1. Set a realistic measurable performance goal. This is important, you can optimize code forever, so you have to have some definition of 'good enough' and stop once your code is good enough.
2. Measure if there is an actual performance problem (by comparing actual performance to your definition of 'good enough').
3. Identify the parts of your code that cause the performance problem; that involves measuring again. For example measure how much time the program spends in each method, then measure how much time the operations in the slow methods take. Do this until you know for sure what makes your program run slow.
4. Optimize the code that you found out to be slow in step 3 and measure again, to make sure your optimizations are making your code run faster (it's suprising how many 'optimizations' actually make things worse).
5. Go back to 2.

Yes, I know, optimizing code is fun - but you can quickly get lost and spend hundreds of hours optimizing code that never needed any optimization.

Comment: Good answer, thanks. Actually I have measured and in my context I gained like 30% increase in speed for the method when this is called (it is called a lot of times). It is indeed a personal project.

Answer (score 2):

It can be called a **precomputed local cache immutable field array**.

It is **fine** and definitely is better than computing the value every time.

---

While I say immutable, I do not mean that it is deeply immutable - all of the values can be changed, only the array reference itself is immutable. If you need to pass it to methods that you do not fully trust, then you can pass a copy - if they mess with the values it is their local copy of it.

Please make sure that you use the correct initial values in the first place. To do so you can compute them with: https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=N%5B1%2F2%5E(0..15),+15%5D

```
N[1/2^(0..15), 15]
```

this would produce values

```
{
  1.00000000000000, 
  0.500000000000000, 
  0.250000000000000, 
  0.125000000000000, 
  0.0625000000000000, 
  0.0312500000000000, 
  0.0156250000000000, 
  0.00781250000000000, 
  0.00390625000000000, 
  0.00195312500000000, 
  0.000976562500000000, 
  0.000488281250000000, 
  0.000244140625000000, 
  0.000122070312500000, 
  0.0000610351562500000, 
  0.0000305175781250000
}
```

The type **double** is approximated value and has the maximum of 15 places you can trust also referred to as **significant digits**. Counting starts not from decimal places, but from the highest value. For type **float** it is just 7 and **decimal** is 28. That is why I showed just 15 digits.

Comment: depending on the program structure, passing a copy of the array might result in many copy operations (which implies allocating memory), which might result in an actually worse performance. If you're really going for speed, you want to avoid allocating memory as much as possible.

Comment: The garbage collector works in a manner that it is cheap to allocate memory for short life-span. Creating a copy is actually the recommended approach as allocating memory is very fast and GC does not need to check for multiple contexts if it can dispose of the memory.

Besides in the current case you are talking about allocating memory for the creation of 16 double elements array, that is just 64 bytes total. I do not even want to mention that on PC the compiler itself would probably use branch prediction and use L1 cache if you would put it in a 100m loop.

Comment: When I test your approach on my machine (10 million calls of a method that uses all values from the array, release build), it takes about 300ms without copying the array, about 1.500 ms with copying, so it's about 5 times slower. Still significantly faster than calculating every time, but allocating memory is definitely not for free.

Comment: Sorry, I forgot: For comparison i tested ReadOnlySpan<double>, took about 370 ms.

Comment: @d_hippo ReadOnlySpan<T> is a good wrapper, but it has lots of limitations that are nicely documented under Microsoft docs remarks section. However, you are right, the speed difference can be roughly 0.000113 ms per item for 10m set.

Comment: yes, it's not the solution for every problem, and probably not even needed in this case. I just wanted to point out what you can save by not allocating for every call.